# WakeLock not turning on the screen

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, alarmmanager, android-alarms

I am trying to create a basic alarm clock app. I set the alarm using the `setExact` method of the `AlarmManager`. And then I created a `BroadcastReceiver` that will display a toast and will start a new activity when the previously set alarm goes off. I also have a `WakeLock` in my `BroadcastReceiver` to try to turn on the screen. The `BroadcastReceiver` is working. It is able to receive the event and then created the activity. But the screen is not turning on. I've read and followed a lot of answers of posts like this in SO but I still cant make it work.

This is my code for setting the alarm:

```
alarmIntent = Intent(context, AlarmReceiver::class.java).let { intent ->
        PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 1, intent, 0)
    }

val alarmTime = Calendar.getInstance().apply {
                timeInMillis = System.currentTimeMillis()
                set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, alarmForm.time.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY))
                set(Calendar.MINUTE, alarmForm.time.get(Calendar.MINUTE))
                set(Calendar.SECOND, 0)
            }

alarmManager.setExact(
                AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,
                alarmTime.timeInMillis,
                alarmIntent
            )
```

This is my `BroadcastReceiver`:

```
class AlarmReceiver : BroadcastReceiver() {
    override fun onReceive(context: Context, intent: Intent) {

        val wakeLock: PowerManager.WakeLock =
            (context.getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE) as PowerManager).run {
                newWakeLock(PowerManager.PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK, "MyApp::MyWakelockTag").apply {
                    acquire(10*60*1000L /*10 minutes*/)
                }
            }

        Toast.makeText(context, "Wake Up!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()

        val alarmDisplayIntent = Intent(context, AlarmDisplayActivity::class.java)
        alarmDisplayIntent.flags = Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK
        context.startActivity(alarmDisplayIntent)

        wakeLock.release()
    }
}
```

And this is the activity I display when alarm goes off:

```
class AlarmDisplayActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_alarm_display)
        window.addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON)
    }

    override fun onResume() {
        super.onResume()
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O_MR1) {
            setTurnScreenOn(true)
        }
    }
}
```

I am using a phone with android version 9. My `minSdkVersion` is 21.
What do you think I am doing wrong or am I missing something?

Comment: A `WaveLock` does not turn the screen on, a `WaveLock` prevents the screen from going off. I think the solution is in https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity#setTurnScreenOn(boolean)

Comment: Sadly, it doesn't work

Comment: Could you update your question with the changes you made to your code?

Comment: Done. Check my AlarmDisplayActivity code

Comment: I suspect `super.onResume()` is using the value of `setTurnScreenOn(true)`, but `setTurnScreenOn(true)` is not called yet when `super.onResume()` is called. Try moving `setTurnScreenOn(true)` to your `onCreate`

Comment: Still the screen doesn't turn on

Comment: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity#setShowWhenLocked(boolean)